# How to downgrade Thunderbird 12.04 to Thunderbird 11.01.1 on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Tags: 10.04

On several Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS systems I've recently upgraded to Thunderbird 11.01.1 to 12.04 via "apt-get update/upgrade". Now my T-Bird menu's drop off un-expectantly; trying to click on "Get Mail" sometimes fails intermittently; and printing is also intermittent. I did not have these intermittent problems before upgrading. How do I revert Thunderbird to the previous release until the developers fix these issues?

Answer (score 2):

To downgrade a package in ubuntu will follow this way

```
sudo apt-get install <pkg_name=Version>
```

in the version name place the version you want .

i mean like `sudo apt-get install thunderbird=11.01.1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's some info on downgrading apps on Ubuntu.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29584/safely-remove-ppas-and-roll-back-to-stable-versions-in-ubuntu/

[image: gnome tweak tool]